# Thymeleaf - How to remove the last character of a string

Tags: java, thymeleaf

In the Thymeleaf template engine, how can I remove the last character of a String? For example, if I have the following expression:

```
<td th:text="${person.someProperty}"></td>
```

How should I remove the last character of the ${person.someProperty} string, and let it only display the remaining string? I'm trying to use a combination of #strings.substring() and #strings.length(), but have not made it work yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string function substring to remove last character in thymeleaf e.g.

`<td th:text="${#strings.substring(person.someProperty, 0, #strings.length(person.someProperty)-1)}"></td>`

Comment: Thanks. But with this approach I'm getting the exception: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: beginIndex must be >= 0 and < 4". My String is four-character long.

Comment: is your property fixed to have 4 characters ?

Comment: No the length is not fixed.

Comment: I think it should be working now, i have tested the same here. Please confirm

Comment: It works! Thanks. One more follow up question if possible: is there a simple way to combine null check and the substring operation? For example, to display the string without the last character only when the string is not null, otherwise show an empty <td>? Now inside the <td> I'm wrapping the string inside a <th:block th:if="${person.someProperty != null}"> element, but I wonder if there's a simpler way to achieve this.

Comment: Sure you can check it as  <td th:text="${person.someProperty !=null ? #strings.substring(person.someProperty, 0, #strings.length(person.someProperty)-1):''}"></td>